# WP_Query $gallerypage->the_post() giving Undefined offset: 0

Tags: theme-development

When I do

```
$gallerypage = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'pagename' => 'gallery'
));

$gallerypage->the_post();
```

the last line `$gallerypage->the_post();` is giving me errors. Why is that? It seems correct?

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 2719
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3491
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3493
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3495
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3496
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3503
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/query.php on line 3514
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 30
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /site/url/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 30
```

wp-includes/query.php line 2717 onwards

```
$this->current_post++;

$this->post = $this->posts[$this->current_post]; // error here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@JM at Work:**

Try wrapping `$gallerypage->the_post();` with `if ($gallerypage->have_posts()): ... endif;`

It should look like this:

```
if ($gallerypage->have_posts()):
  $gallerypage->the_post();
endif;
```

See:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting the page to exists so I skipped that for simplicity, but backfired ... I should be searching for a "page" instead of a "post"

Comment: @JM at Work - So my reply answered your question, or not?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mark it as answer